# Method differs only by optional parameters error

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
Function GetAuthor(entityId As Integer, authorId As Integer, Optional ByVal authorImageWidth As Integer = 250) As String

Function GetAuthor(entityId As Integer, authorId As Integer, feedId As Integer, Optional ByVal authorImageWidth As Integer = 250) As String
```

I don't know whats wrong with this. I am getting this error message.

> 'Function GetAuthor(entityId As Integer, authorId As Integer, [authorImageWidth As Integer = 250]) As String' and 'Function GetAuthor(entityId As Integer, authorId As Integer, feedId As Integer, [authorImageWidth As Integer = 250]) As String' cannot overload each other because they differ only by optional parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call GetAuthor(int, int, int) the compiler will have no clue which of the 2 methods you want since both would be suitable (and that is what this message is telling you)

If you remove the optional part of your second method it will compile since 
`GetAuthor(int, int)` and `GetAuthor(int, int, int)` can only resolve to your first method and `GetAuthor(int, int, int, int)` to your second thus making the overload unique by it's parameters

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a way to differentiate between all these possible calls:

```
GetAuthor(entityId, authorId)
GetAuthor(entityId, authorId, authorImageWidth)    
GetAuthor(entityId, authorId, feedId)              
GetAuthor(entityId, authorId, feedId, authorImageWidth)
```

the 2nd and 3rd line have the same signature. An alternative would be change the name of one of the functions, or to define the `authorImageWidth` somewhere else, or to change the type of `authorImageWidth` to `String` or something other than `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is confused about which method to resolve.

What if you called

```
GetAuthor(1, 1, 250)
```

How should the compiler decide which one to call?

"Hmm... maybe they meant this guy because there isn't a 3rd parameter."

```
Function GetAuthor(entityId As Integer, authorId As Integer, Optional ByVal authorImageWidth As Integer = 250) As String
```

"But wait!  This guy requires a 3rd parameter but the 4th is optional."

```
Function GetAuthor(entityId As Integer, authorId As Integer, feedId As Integer, Optional ByVal authorImageWidth As Integer = 250) As String
```

"As the compiler, I'm confused, therefore I'm going to let you know."

Both are valid because, as the compiler has already told you, it **... cannot overload each other because they differ only by optional parameters.**