# C# Methods differ only by optional parameters

Tags: c#

I have found this topic, but it's VB...and they get an error:
[vb issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547355/method-differs-only-by-optional-parameters-error)

Here are my method signatures.  Notice one has a different return type.

```
public static bool PopulateRunWithSimpleValueByFieldIdSync(string fieldValue, string fieldId, IViewModel myself, int index)
```

VS

```
public static void PopulateRunWithSimpleValueByFieldIdSync(string fieldValue, string fieldId, IViewModel myself, int index = 0, PopulateDoneCallback populateDone = null)
```

The actual call I was making:

```
PopulateRunWithSimpleValueByFieldIdSync(date, dtx.DateField, saver, index);
```

The compiler decided to pick the first method, and not give me an error.  Once the first method was removed (it was unused code), it started calling the second method.

Is there an option somewhere to treat this as an error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: aren't you getting a warning, or is this just with ReSharper (spoiled me ...) ...?

Comment: Optional parameters are evil. Necessary evil :(

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair There is no warning from the compiler.

Comment: Easy to do using Roslyn, but would only work with VS2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to use some form of 3rd party code analysis if you want this to be flagged at compile time, since the C# language specs define the current behavior as what should happen.

Comment: a link to the spec would be the cherry on top, maybe even a quote - just to prove your statement ;) you knew this upfront to end in a spec-hunt ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair The OP isn't asserting that the compiler is buggy in that it behaves as it does.  He's not asking if this is valid C#, he's asking how to make the compiler throw an error.  There is no section of the specs that will state that the compiler doesn't have a feature to make this an error; the specs state what it does, not all of the features it doesn't have.

Comment: @Servy: Though it might be useful to refer to documentation which explains the method overload resolution.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Method overload resolution is a pretty large section of the specs.  It's a full chapter.

Comment: @Servy: Okay, you are right. Already upvoted, but I thought it might add something to your post.

Comment: @Servy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx ... the crucial information with the optional-thing is in there - no need for a whole section!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair And if the question was asking why that overload was preferred over the other then it would be relevant to the answer, but that isn't the question.  The question says that he *knows* that the one overload is preferred over the other and he's asking how to *make the code he knows is correct result in a compiler error*.  Adding that information is telling the OP what the question is already stating.

Answer (score 1):

This is per design, according to the [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

> Use of named and optional arguments affects overload resolution in the
>   following ways:
>
> - A method, indexer, or constructor is a candidate for execution if each of its parameters either is optional or corresponds, by name or
>     by position, to a single argument in the calling statement, and that
>     argument can be converted to the type of the parameter.
> - If more than one candidate is found, overload resolution rules for preferred conversions are applied to the arguments that are explicitly
>     specified. Omitted arguments for optional parameters are ignored.
> - If two candidates are judged to be equally good, **preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments
>     were omitted in the call.** This is a consequence of a general
>     preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer
>     parameters.

So, no - you can't.

Comment: @PatrickHofmann good catch ... but somehow it does in an intrinsic way: if this is per design and the compiler's default behaviour, how can you generate an error at compile-time? adding checking at runtime would mean significant overhead.

Comment: The question is asking *how he can force the code in question to result in an error*; it's not asking why the code in question compiles or why the first overload is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [C# language guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) (**emphasis** mine),

> > Use of named and optional arguments affects overload resolution in the following ways:
> >
> > ...
> >
> > If two candidates are judged to be equally good, **preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call**. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters.

You can use a third party analysis tool to flag this as an error or to use Visual Studio's built in static code analysis too with a custom rule that you implement.